# implicit declaration of function itoa is invalid in c99

Tags: c

When I try use the function `itoa()`, I get the warning:

> implicit declaration of function  is invalid in c99.

I have included stdlib.h on my header. I'm trying to call this function inside a function, I'm not sure if this is allowed.

Comment: @maxflow: Where have you declared `itoa`?

Comment: @CharlesBailey I have tried declaring itoa both in main and inside a function and I get the same error.

Comment: So long as you declare it before you use it you shouldn't get the error that you've posted. Please post code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that itoa() isn't a standard function.

You should take a look at [this link](http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/) which gives you some alternative implementations

Comment: His problem is that itoa is avaliable for the linker but there is no c definition for it. Declaring char* itoa(int, char* , int); should solve the problem.

Comment: waynix, what do you mean? why would he need to declare it? you mean that the kind of error says that the linker found the symbol, but it is forbidding him to use it unless he declares it? In that case, wouldn't it be better to include a header that declares it?

Comment: He gets a warning, not an error, so the function 'exists' somewhere in the compiler toolchain or in the linker files. One way to remove the warning is using a implementation like the one in your link. But he could also just declare the function and the problem is gone. If that is a sane choice is another question.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative that is commonly used in place of `itoa` is `sprintf`/`snprintf`. These are part of `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 4):

As @Mike Kwan pointed out. Sprintf can be used as follows,

```
int load = 15;
char buffer[100];

sprintf(buffer,"%d",load);

printf("buffer in int = %s\n",buffer);
```

Comment: `sprintf` takes a lot of RAM in my PIC16F877A. `itoa` is much better in that regard.