# Error: Implicit declaration of function

Tags: objective-c, c, c99

The code I have below has an error.  It says implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99.

I'm not too sure on how to fix this.

```
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162465/implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-in-c99)

Comment: Some confusion: Is it C99 or objective C?

Comment: Objective C  I have still got the same problem though.  Thanks for that help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import the headers required for OpenGL?

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

Comment: No.  How would I do that?

Comment: You need to put the code in my answer at the top of your file by the other import(s).

Comment: Ok.  I already had that in there. In the ViewController.h file

Comment: And you're still getting the implicit declaration error? `glGenVertexArraysOES` is declared on line 468 of my `glext.h` file, so this should have solved your problem.