# How do I convert an integer to a character in c?

Tags: c, types

This works:

```
int  a = 7;

char b = a + '0';

write(1,&b,1);
```

but this does not:

```
int a = 7;

char b = (char) a;

write(1,&b,1);
```

Could someone tell me why? I just want to convert the integer 7 to '7' as a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `char` is just a narrow integer type - on most systems it's 8 bits wide, meaning it can store values from `[-128..127]` (signed) or `[0..255]` (unsigned)<sup>1</sup>.

When you write

```
int a = 7;
char b = (char) a;
```

you're still assigning the integer value `7` to `b` - it's just being stored in a narrower integer type.  It's not being converted to the *encoding* for the character symbol `'7'`.

In ASCII and UTF-8, the encoding for the character symbol `'7'` is `55`.  The encoding for the character symbol `'0'` is `48`, so you can add `7` to `'0'` to get the encoding for the character `'7'`.

The value `7` is the encoding for the ASCII control character `BEL` - it rings the bell on the console.

---

1. Plain `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the platform.

Comment: also keep in mind that 

`int a = 7 + '0'`
and 
`write(1, &a, 1)`

will also work fine.

Comment: OMG! That's why my Macbook made that sound! Thank you so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To convert an integer to a string you can use the `sprintf()`. The answer can be found in another topic: [implicit declaration of function itoa is invalid in c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162465/implicit-declaration-of-function-itoa-is-invalid-in-c99)

Here is the code posted in the answer of Deekshith Patil:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
int load = 15;
char buffer[100];

sprintf(buffer,"%d",load);

printf("buffer in int = %s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

This will take your integer value and convert it to a string.

Comment: Thank you, not quite the explanation I was hoping for, but thank you :)

Comment: Now I understand the question... You are hoping an explanation for the error, not another way to convert XD my bad